# $_GET не выводится.

Tags: php

Где здесь ошибка?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HD-Video</title>
<style>
        html {height: 100%; overflow: hidden;} 
        body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background: #000;}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s12.ucoz.net/src/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://mp3rai.moy.su/d.js"></script>
<script>
var oid = '<?php $_GET['m'] ?>';
var id = '<?php $_GET["id"] ?>';
var hash = '<?php $_GET["hash"] ?>';
</script>
<div class="player" id="videoplayer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и не будет выдаваться, у вас не написано ЧТО надо сделать с гетом. 

Типа как:

$a = 10;
$a;

Надо:
$a = 10;
print $a;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала поробуйте вывести весь массив $_GET.
Вот так!

`print_r($_GET).`

Если данные, которые вам нужны есть, тогда выводить их вот так:

```
<?echo $_GET["id"]?>
```

Скорей всего, у вас в фраймворке не подключено сокращение слово echo, поэтому пишите полностью.

Answer (score 4):

Исправьте строчки на:

```
<?=$_GET["id"]?>
```

или

```
<?php echo $_GET["id"]?>
```

не?

Comment: точняк. вот мы слепцы

Answer (score 2):

```
var oid = '<?php $_GET['m'] ?>';
```

тут неэкраннированные кавычки, поэтому js скрипт валится. Сделайте так:

```
var oid = '<?php $_GET["m"] ?>';
```

Comment: Попробывал, не работает. У меня не скрипт валится, а php содержимое из GET не передается, чтобы скрипт начал работать.

Comment: может быть, Вы просто не передаете эти параметры?

Comment: Все я передаю, не надо из меня уж тотального дурака то делать, все передается, но не выводится на простом хостинге с php

Comment: @dbaishev

> Попробывал

попроб**о**вал

> а php содержимое из GET не передается, чтобы скрипт начал работать.

что под этим подразумевается? выводится пустота? выводятся php-теги?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_GET[id]; ?>
```

URL:

Ваш_сайт.домен/?id=Число которое надо вывести.

А лучше пользуйтесь POST запросом, он безопаснее.